# multiple features in collaborative filtering- spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, collaborative-filtering, apache-spark-mllib

I have a CSV file that looks like:

```
customer_ID, location, ....other info..., item-bought, score
```

I am trying to build a collaborative filtering recommender in Spark. Spark takes data of the form:

```
userID, itemID, value
```

but my data is longer, I want all user's info to be used instead of just `userID`. I tried grouping the columns in one column as:

```
(customerID,location,....),itemID,score
```

but the `ALS.train` gives me this error:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

How can I let spark take multiple key/values and not only three columns?
thanks

Comment: If train() wants a string of a number, that indicates that it expects some sort of identifier. You could either mash your column values together and make long strings, or even better associate each tuple to an integer identifier and provide this. Create a table in a relational database and use the row number.

Comment: Important: You should add columns to your identifier only if you want them to separate your data. In what you typed above, you seem to be saying that the same customer at two different locations should be treated as different customers. Make sure this is what you want.

Comment: Yes I want same customer with different locations to be treated as different. So, if I map each customer row to an identifier then will my recommender take his specific information into considerations?

Comment: Yes it will treat them as distinct entities. Also note that the same reasoning applies to the items

Comment: You can create an indexed RDD with distinct values parameter (customerID,location,....) using the zipWithUniqueId method and then use the index as a user instead for your Rating object.

Comment: I would recommend a Tensor Factorization instead of Matrix one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each customer, identify the columns which you would like to use to distinguish these user-entities. Create a table (e.g. in SQL) in which each row contains the information for one user-entity, and use the row number in this table as the userID.

Do the same for your items if necessary, and provide these IDs to your classifier.